# count words of regex pattern in php?

Tags: php, regex, linux

I'm trying to match pattern 'lly' from '/usr/share/dict/words' in linux and I can display them in the browser. I want to count how many words that matches the pattern and display the total at the end of output. This is my php script.

```
<?php
$dfile = fopen("/usr/share/dict/words", "r");
while(!feof($dfile)) {
$mynextline = fgets($dfile);
if (preg_match("/lly/", $mynextline)) echo "$mynextline<br>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the count function to count how many elements of an array they are. So you simply just add to this array each time, and then count it.

```
<?php
$dfile = fopen("/usr/share/dict/words", "r");
//Create an empty array
$array_to_count = array();
while(!feof($dfile)) {
$mynextline = fgets($dfile);
if (preg_match("/lly/", $mynextline)){
    echo "$mynextline<br>";
    //Add it to the array
    $array_to_count[] = $mynextline;
}
}
//Now we're at the end so show the amount
echo count($array_to_count);
?>
```

A simpler way if you don't want to store all of the values (which might come in handy, but anyway) is to just increment to an integer variable like so:

```
<?php
$dfile = fopen("/usr/share/dict/words", "r");
//Create an integer variable
$count = 0;
while(!feof($dfile)) {
$mynextline = fgets($dfile);
if (preg_match("/lly/", $mynextline)){
    echo "$mynextline<br>";
    //Add it to the var
    $count++;
}
}
//Show the number here
echo $count;
?>
```

Comment: Hi Chris, I'm getting the output something like this. 2424acronichally 
25252525acronycally 
262626acronychally 
272727272727acronymically 
28282828282828282828282828acropetally 
29292929acrophonically

Comment: Oops, I put the echo inside the while loop. Just knock it down a line, I'll update my answer now. - There we go. That should work nicely.

Answer (score 1):

[PHP: Glob - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php)

```
sizeof(glob("/lly/*"));
```

@edit

Also, you can do like this:

```
$array = glob("/usr/share/dict/words/lly/*")

foreach ($array as $row)
{
    echo $row.'<br>';
}

echo count($array);
```

Comment: Would it not be better to avoid searching the pattern a 2nd time if they're already doing it once? Given a large file, this might cause unnecessary lag issues. Would make more sense to me to put something inside the already-present loop.

Comment: That worked!! Chris!!. Thanks alot!! Now I have to check the script given by @Gabriel.